# Heartbeat request to virtual charge station

Tags: javascript, node.js, ocpp

I'm developing central system sofware for managing EV charging stations in Node.js. I am using ocpp-js library. After creating virtual charging point, i make request as

`chargingPoint.heartbeat();`

and after this request, virtual charge point send to draft central system. message in xml format within logs is written below.

```
[ChargingPoint] Creating Client for Central System Service
[2022-07-18 16:01:34] [info] "Handling POST on /Ocpp/CentralSystemService"
[2022-07-18 16:01:34] [received] "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">\n  <soap:Header>\n    <h:chargeBoxIdentity xmlns:h=\"urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/\">Simulator 1</h:chargeBoxIdentity>\n    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:97fda734-4a3c-4d6e-a7e6-b4d4c9936aae</a:MessageID>\n    <a:From>\n      <a:Address>http://localhost:9221/Ocpp/ChargePointService</a:Address>\n    </a:From>\n    <a:ReplyTo>\n      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>\n    </a:ReplyTo>\n    <a:To>http://localhost:9220/Ocpp/CentralSystemService</a:To>\n    <a:Action soap:mustUnderstand=\"1\">/Heartbeat</a:Action>\n  </soap:Header>\n  <soap:Body>\n    <ns1:heartbeatRequest xmlns:ns1=\"urn://Ocpp/Cs/2012/06/\"/>\n  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"
[2022-07-18 16:01:34] [info] "Attempting to bind to /Ocpp/CentralSystemService"
[2022-07-18 16:01:34] [info] "Trying CentralSystemServiceSoap12 from path /Ocpp/CentralSystemService"
```

XML content is:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><soap:Header>
    <h:chargeBoxIdentity xmlns:h=\"urn://Ocpp/Cp/2012/06/\">Simulator 1</h:chargeBoxIdentity>    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:97fda734-4a3c-4d6e-a7e6-b4d4c9936aae</a:MessageID>    <a:From>    <a:Address>http://localhost:9221/Ocpp/ChargePointService</a:Address></a:From>    
<a:ReplyTo>      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>\n    </a:ReplyTo>    <a:To>http://localhost:9220/Ocpp/CentralSystemService</a:To>    <a:Action soap:mustUnderstand=\"1\">/Heartbeat</a:Action>  
</soap:Header>  
<soap:Body>    
<ns1:heartbeatRequest xmlns:ns1=\"urn://Ocpp/Cs/2012/06/\"/>  </soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>
```

and full code is written below:

**app.js**

```
var OCPP =  require('ocpp-js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


var options = {
  centralSystem: {
    port: 9220
  },
  chargingPoint: {
    serverURI: 'http://localhost:9221/Ocpp/ChargePointService',
    name: 'Simulator 1'
  },
  chargingPointServer: {
    port: 9221
  }
}

var ocppJS = new OCPP(options);

// Create Central System
var centralSystem = ocppJS.createCentralSystem();

// Create Charging Point Client
var chargingPoint1 = ocppJS.createChargingPoint('http://127.0.0.1:8081/ChargeBox/Ocpp', "chargingPoint1-Simulator");
//var chargingPoint2 = ocppJS.createChargingPoint('http://localhost:9221/Ocpp/ChargePointService', "chargingPoint2-Simulator");

// Charging Point Params can be also taken from options
//var chargingPoint1 = ocppJS.createChargingPoint();

// Create Charging Point Server
//var chargingPointServer = ocppJS.createChargingPointServer(9221);

//centralSystem.createChargeBoxClient(chargingPoint1);
centralSystem.clients.push(chargingPoint1);
 console.log(centralSystem);
 

 app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    chargingPoint1.heartbeat();
 });

 app.get('/bootNot', (req, res, next) => {
    res.json(chargingPoint1.bootNotification({req: "BootNotification"}));
 });

 app.get('/meterVal', (req, res, next) => {
    chargingPoint1.meterValues({meterValueRequest: "REQ"});
 });

 app.get('/getId', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json(chargingPoint1.getId());
 });
 
 app.listen(5000, (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("App is listening");
 });
```

I have a few quesions:

My first question is about completion of mission: according to logs has the heartbeat request completed successfully or not?

My last question is that if i create a SOAP server and sending request to soap clients (EV Charging units) with OCPP1.5 compliant data (maybe i'll use my own lib instead of occp-js), my created server can be accepted as an OCPP server?

Comment: For your first question I'd say that the fact you have received a response from a heartbeat request is indicative of success. The heartbeat test is usually asking "can I get a response back" and you have done so.

Comment: Nice project, you might want to consider using mqtt (e.G. [Mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/)) for such tasks -> has QOS with different levels, heartbeats, testaments/last-will etc.. What you are doing isn't a heartbeat exactly since it would be emitted from the EV-station - you are doing more of a handsdhake (req -> ack)..